# Gson - attempting to convert json string to custom object

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

Here is my Json returned from the server

```
{"ErrorCode":1005,"Message":"Username does not exist"}
```

Here is my class for an error

```
public class ErrorModel {
public int ErrorCode;
public String Message;
}
```

and here is my conversion code.

```
public static ErrorModel GetError(String json) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try
    {
        ErrorModel err = gson.fromJson(json, ErrorModel.class);

        return err;
    }
    catch(JsonSyntaxException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is always throwing a JsonSyntaxException.  Any ideas what could be my problem here?

**EDIT**: As requested, here is further elaboration.

My backend is an ASP.NET MVC 2 application acting as a rest API.  The backend isn't the problem here, as my actions (and even server errors) all return Json (using the built in `JsonResult`).  Here's a sample.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest request)
{
    var authResult = mobileService.Authenticate(request.Username, request.Password, request.AdminPassword);

    switch (authResult.Result)
    {
         //logic omitted for clarity
         default:
            return ExceptionResult(ErrorCode.InvalidCredentials, "Invalid username/password");
            break;
    }

    var user = authResult.User;

    string token = SessionHelper.GenerateToken(user.UserId, user.Username);

    var result = new AuthenticateResult()
    {
        Token = token
    };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

The basic logic is to auth the user cretentials and either return an ExceptionModel as json or an AuthenticationResult as json.

Here is my server side Exception Model

```
public class ExceptionModel
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public ExceptionModel() : this(null)
    {

    }

    public ExceptionModel(Exception exception)
    {
        ErrorCode = 500;
        Message = "An unknown error ocurred";

        if (exception != null)
        {
            if (exception is HttpException)
                ErrorCode = ((HttpException)exception).ErrorCode;

            Message = exception.Message;
        }
    }

    public ExceptionModel(int errorCode, string message)
    {
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

When the above authentication is called with invalid credentials, the error result is returned as expected.  The Json returned is the Json above in the question.

On the android side, I first build an object with my key-value pairs.

```
public static HashMap<String, String> GetAuthenticationModel(String username, String password, String adminPassword, String abbr)
{
    HashMap<String, String> request = new HashMap<String, String>();
    request.put("SiteAbbreviation", abbr);
    request.put("Username", username);
    request.put("Password", password);
    request.put("AdminPassword", adminPassword);

    return request;
}
```

Then, I send off an http post and return as a string whatever is sent back.

```
public static String Post(ServiceAction action, Map<String, String> values) throws IOException {
    String serviceUrl = GetServiceUrl(action);

    URL url = new URL(serviceUrl);

    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    String data = GetPairsAsString(values);

    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.writeBytes(data);
    output.flush();
    output.close();

    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

    String line;
    String result = "";
    while (null != ((line = input.readLine())))
    {
        result += line;
    }
    input.close ();

    return result;
}

private static String GetServiceUrl(ServiceAction action)
{
    return "http://192.168.1.5:33333" + action.toString();
}

private static String GetPairsAsString(Map<String, String> values){

    String result = "";
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter = values.entrySet().iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, String>)iter.next();

        result += "&" + pairs.getKey() + "=" + pairs.getValue();
    }

    //remove the first &
    return result.substring(1);
}
```

Then I take that result and pass it into my parser to see if it is an error

```
public static ErrorModel GetError(String json) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try
    {
        ErrorModel err = gson.fromJson(json, ErrorModel.class);

        return err;
    }
    catch(JsonSyntaxException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But, JsonSyntaxException is always thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might help to know more about the exception, but the same code sample works fine here. I suspect there's a piece of code you omitted that's causing the problem (perhaps the creation/retrieval of the JSON string). Here's a code sample that worked fine for me on Java 1.6 and Gson 1.6:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class ErrorModel {
  public int ErrorCode;
  public String Message;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\"ErrorCode\":1005,\"Message\":\"Username does not exist\"}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ErrorModel err = gson.fromJson(json, ErrorModel.class);
    System.out.println(err.ErrorCode);
    System.out.println(err.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: The Json is created in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application and retrieved through an http post.

Comment: I took your code as a test and tried it and it also throws a JsonSyntaxException, even with the hard coded json string as you have.  I have the latest java (1.6) and the latest gson (1.6)

Comment: To me code and JSON look correct, so I don't know how you could get the issue. But if you can't get things to work with Gson, perhaps you should consider alternatives.